# Script Very Slow on Windows 10

Tags: python

I am running the code below on Windows 10. It takes a long time to start, a long time to run and a long time to stop. When I run it on a Windows 8.1 machine it works fine. After some research I added python and the various folders as exclusions to Windows Defender but that hasn't made a difference.

The memory and CPU are nowhere near maxed so I cannot work out what the issue is. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
import pyautogui as py
from pyclick.humancurve import HumanCurve

class HumanClicker():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def move(self, fromPoint, toPoint, duration=2, humanCurve=None):

        if not humanCurve:
            humanCurve = HumanCurve(fromPoint, toPoint)

        py.PAUSE = duration / len(humanCurve.points)
        for point in humanCurve.points:
            py.moveTo(point)
hc = HumanClicker()
hc.move((100, 100), (150, 150), 0.1)
```

Comment: How is the performance for a trivial script such as `print("hello, world")`?

Comment: Are you using the same versions of pyautogui and pyclick on both systems?

Comment: @jarmod that is slower than it should be as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy they are the same versions on each machine

Comment: Do you have other anti-virus? Are you running Python as administrative user?

Comment: How long is "long"?

Comment: @jarmod no I don't

Comment: @KellyBundy I've just run a test with 'timeit'. On Win10 it takes 1.56s and on Win8.1 it's 0.11s

Answer (score 0):

So after spending the weekend trying to figure it out I haven't been able to fix it. I ended up removing Windows 10 and installing 8.1. Everything works ok now.